# Setting default to 0 in vuechart.js HorizontalBar

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I'm making a vuechart.js Horizontal Barchart, and I want the minimum/default to be set to 0. I am a noob, however. So I do not know if I am coding the "options" right. I tried a few things but nothing seems to have effect on the axys.

My latest try:

```
export default ({
extends: HorizontalBar,
props: ['agentTickets', 'options'],
mounted() {
    this.renderChart({
        labels: ['Ferry', 'Carlo', 'Menno', 'Scott'],   
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Yeet', backgroundColor: 'black', data: [10, 20, 30, 40]
        }]     
    }, 
    {
        responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false
    },
    {
        scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
            },
            stacked: true
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
            },
            stacked: true
        }]
        },
    })
}    
})
```

Another of my attempts:

```
export default {
extends: HorizontalBar,
props: ['agentTickets', 'options'],
mounted() {
    this.renderChart({
        labels: ['Ferry', 'Carlo', 'Menno', 'Scott'],   
        scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                    },
                    stacked: true
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                    },
                    stacked: true
                }]
        },
        datasets: [
            {label: 'Yeet', backColor: 'black', data: [10, 20, 30, 40]}
        ]     
    }, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false})

}    
}
```

And one more just because!

```
export default {
extends: HorizontalBar,
props: ['agentTickets', 'options'],
mounted() {
    this.renderChart({
        labels: ['Ferry', 'Carlo', 'Menno', 'Scott'],   
        options: {
            scale: {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0,
                    },
                    stacked: true
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0,
                    },
                    stacked: true
                }]
            }
        },
        datasets: [
            {label: 'Yeet', backdropColor: 'black', data: [10, 20, 30, 40]}
        ]     
    }, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false})

}    
}
```

(I've tried the latest example with beginAtZero too)

[image]

Above are the current results, what I want is a graph that starts at 0, instead of 10.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Appearantly the options was already created (where responsive and maintainAspectRatio were defined). Just copied the scales between those curly bracers and it works!